# How to fix 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i'm currently trying to make a website that show distance, routes and price (for clients who want a taxi) but when i added a function to multiply the distance by a coefficiant, everything started not working.
the errors i got in the console are:

'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
   script:42'

'Uncaught (in promise) Vc {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Vc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…rGYVNAJV_cj_TFD9lhMIKy51o&callback=initMap:122:96"}'

```
function initMap() {
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  zoom: 7,
  center: { lat: 45.75, lng: 4.85 }
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var onChangeHandler = function() {
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
};
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("change", onChangeHandler);
document.getElementById("end").addEventListener("change", onChangeHandler);




}function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
directionsService.route(
  {
    origin: document.getElementById("start").value,
    destination: document.getElementById("end").value,
    travelMode: "DRIVING"
  },
  function(response, status) {
    if (status === "OK") {
      document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML =
        "la distance total du trajet est: " +
        (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000).toFixed(2) +
        " km";
        /*
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML =
        "Vous devrez donc payer:" +
        ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 2.5).toFixed(
          2
        ) +
        "€";*/
      //alert('Total travel distance is: ' + (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' km');
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      //window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  )}
  function tarifs(response, status){
    var hours = document.querySelector('#hours');
    if(7<=hours.value<=19){
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML =
        "Vous devrez donc payer:" +
        ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 1.66).toFixed(2) + "€";
    }else if(19<=hours.value<=23){
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML =
        "Vous devrez donc payer:" +
        ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 2.50).toFixed(2) + "€";
    }else if(0<=hours.value<=7){
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML =
        "Vous devrez donc payer:" +
        ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 2.50).toFixed(2) + "€";
    }
  }
);}
```

Comment: You are missing a `)` - the error tells you on which line it failed, so it should be there somewhere or earlier. Depending on the statements you have, it might not break the syntax for a line or two or something.

Comment: If you use Chrome, open Dev Tools, go to Source, and click the "Pause on Exceptions" icon (a stop sign with the pause icon). Keep the dev tools open and run your function. It should pause the script where an exception happens.

Comment: @Joseph it's a syntax error, it's unlikely to pause there. It's just code that is written in a way the parser cannot comprehend, it's not a runtime problem.

Comment: well i already try to fix that but it still doesn't work so i dont think the problem comes from this line

Comment: by the way i oppened dev tools and it stopped on some code i didn't write,here is what i got: [link](https://imgur.com/zrqcwqJ)

Comment: For info, most editors have a key shortcut allowing to just to a matching delimiter ( or {, and using that on your last line gives the bug position. As beautifying the code also does...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. It's easier to pinpoint the mistake if you beautify your code and use a syntax highlighter like VSCode:

```
  function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {
        lat: 45.75,
        lng: 4.85
      }
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var onChangeHandler = function () {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("change", onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById("end").addEventListener("change", onChangeHandler);
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById("start").value,
      destination: document.getElementById("end").value,
      travelMode: "DRIVING"
    },
      function (response, status) {
        if (status === "OK") {
          document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML =
            "la distance total du trajet est: " +
            (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000).toFixed(2) +
            " km";
          /*
          document.getElementById("price").innerHTML =
            "Vous devrez donc payer:" +
            ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 2.5).toFixed(
              2
            ) +
            "€";*/
          //alert('Total travel distance is: ' + (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' km');
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          //window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
  }

  function tarifs(response, status) {
    var hours = document.querySelector('#hours');
    if (7 <= hours.value <= 19) {
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML =
        "Vous devrez donc payer:" +
        ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 1.66).toFixed(2) + "€";
    } else if (19 <= hours.value <= 23) {
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML =
        "Vous devrez donc payer:" +
        ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 2.50).toFixed(2) + "€";
    } else if (0 <= hours.value <= 7) {
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML =
        "Vous devrez donc payer:" +
        ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 2.50).toFixed(2) + "€";
    }
  }
```